# Oracle SQL Current_Date

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I’m experiencing some issues while using the Current_Date function in a simple query and I haven’t been able to figure out why. I’m working in an Oracle 12c environment using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.

My original query looks something like this:

```
select * from Inventory where Placement_End_Dt >= Current_date
```

The above works fine except it doesn’t pick up records where Placement_End_Dt is today (14th May 18)

I attempted to simplify the query as follows, but this also returns nothing

```
select * from Inventory where Placement_End_Dt = Current_date
```

However when I apply date formatting as follows, it works:

```
select * from Inventory where to_char(Placement_End_Dt, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_char(Current_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Then I try and expand on this to revert to my original query to select all records with an end date from today onwards:

```
select * from Inventory where to_char(Placement_End_Dt, 'DD-MM-YYYY') => to_char(Current_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

This fails spectacularly because it selects records with a Placement_End_Dt past, present and future!

The Placement_End_Dt columns is defined as an Oracle DATE data type

Would appreciate some input on how I can get this query to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using this query

```
select * from Inventory where trunc(Placement_End_Dt) = trunc(sysdate);
```

Oracle Date columns also store a timestamp by default, so unless the records were the same down to the second, they won't match. When you use trunc() on a date column, it truncates the timestamp and leaves just the date.

Answer (score 5):

When using `to_char` you are comparing strings.

```
to_char(date '2000-01-20', 'DD-MM-YYYY') > to_char(date '2018-05-14', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

because '20-01-2000' is greater than '14-05-2018', because of the first letters in the strings: '2' > '1'.

And `CURRENT_DATE` is hardly ever used, because it uses your computer's time, rather than the database time, so you can easily be some hours off. Use `SYSDATE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will return the rows for present days and future days.

```
select * from Inventory where trunc(Placement_End_Dt) >= trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: I think that can be simplified to `where placement_end_dt >= trunc(sysdate);`